# Grothendieck universe - a question regarding to its definition

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

I can not grasp this line in the definition of Grothendieck universe:

(3): If u∈U then the power set P(u)∈U

( The definition is taken from
[https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Grothendieck_Universe#:~:text=A%20Grothendieck%20universe%20allows%20us,his%20studies%20of%20algebraic%20geometry.](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Grothendieck_Universe#:%7E:text=A%20Grothendieck%20universe%20allows%20us,his%20studies%20of%20algebraic%20geometry.))

Does this imply that "u" is necessarily a set? If not, what does it mean to have power set of it? Isn't it true that power set is only defined for a set?

Comment: In the ZF framework, everything is a set.

Comment: Thank you for your attention @spaceisdarkgreen. But a question, is this also true for set members? That is: in ZF even the members of a set are sets?

Comment: **Everything** is a set.

Comment: Yes, literally every mathematical object.

Comment: Thanks very much; now I see. I will remember this: any set is essentially a set of set.